# Передача переменных в паттерне MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

Не могу разобраться со связью VM<>M. Точнее как грамотно передавать переменные.

Скажем есть настройки введенные пользователем, они передаются с V в VM при помощи Binding. А вот как правильно дальше передать...

У меня есть два варианта:

1. Делать класс настроек статичным.
2. Передавать настройки из класса в класс в M. То есть гонять настройки по всем классам.

Честно говоря мне эти варианты не очень нравятся, я думаю, что есть более грамотный вариант. Могу ошибаться, так как недавно изучаю C#.

Интересует двунаправленная связь, что бы из VM в M и наоборот.

Буду так же рад ссылке на **хорошее** описание паттерна, где бы описывались все этапы.

Comment: "А вот как правильно дальше передать..." Куда дальше то? VM работает с экземплярами модели, если надо сохранить состояние модели, то через класс репозитория происходит сохранение состояния моделей в БД или в файлы.

Comment: В каком-то случае можно посмотреть Mediator pattern для организации общения между разными частями системы. Наверное, ответ не в кассу, но вопрос же про передачу переменных... Ну типа организовать событийную систему. http://udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/

Comment: @Bulson, в M. И не для хранения, а для работы. Допусти пользователь задает путь. Как возможно его го переда для дальнейшей работы в M и передаче обратно ответа?

Comment: @AndreyK. В принципе подчеркнул для себя некоторые вещи, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробую ответить на ваш вопрос подробнее, т.к. вы просите: "Буду так же рад ссылке на хорошее описание паттерна...". Про сам паттерн теоретическую информацию с картинками найти легко. А вот подробных примеров с нуля создания проекта найти уже сложнее.

Мы с вами создадим простейший пример. И пойдем мы снизу, т.е. с создания модели и ее сохранения в `xml` файл, а затем уже поднимемся выше и создадим WPF приложение. Да, и вьюмодель мы создадим в отдельном проекте, чтоб, как говорится, вы почувствовали разницу.

1) *Модель*

Создайте пустое решение
[image: пустое решение]

В нем создайте проект библиотеки `StudBL` (BL - business logic)
[image: проект библиотеки StudBL]

И в нем у нас будет один класс модели - Студент (сделаем все максимально простым, чтоб не рябило в глазах от многих строк кода)

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}-{Name}";
    }
}
```

И еще добавим сюда интерфейс, в котором опишем основные манипуляции с данными модели. Обычно их кратко называют CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete), мы опять же опишем минимум.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get();
    TEntity Get(int id);

    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Remove(TEntity entity);
}
```

2) *Данные*

Создайте проект библиотеки `StudDAL` (DAL - data access layer).
Данные для простоты мы будет сохранять в файл `xml`, потому создадим абстрактный класс работы с таким файлом.

```
public abstract class XmlFileService<TEntity>
{
    protected readonly string _fileName;

    //ctor
    public XmlFileService(string fileName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileName));
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<TEntity> ReadData();
    public abstract void WriteData(IEnumerable<TEntity> collection);
}
```

А теперь класс, который непосредственно будет читать и писать в файл (В References добавьте ссылку на `StudBL`)

```
public class StudentFileService : XmlFileService<Student>
{
    private const string _root = "studens";
    private const string _element = "student";
    private const string _attribute = "id";
    private const string _property = "name";

    public StudentFileService(string fileName) : base(fileName)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Student> ReadData()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(_fileName))
        {
            return new List<Student>();
        }

        return ReadFile();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Student> ReadFile()
    {
        XDocument document;
        List<Student> result = new List<Student>();

        try
        {
            document = XDocument.Load(_fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"<--{ex.Message}");
            return result;
        }

        foreach (var item in document.Descendants(_root).Elements(_element))
        {
            int id = Int32.Parse(item.Attribute(_attribute).Value);
            string name = item.Element(_property).Value;

            result.Add(new Student { Id = id, Name = name });
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteData(IEnumerable<Student> collection)
    {
        XElement students = new XElement(_root);
        foreach (var student in collection)
        {
            var s = new XElement(_element, new XAttribute(_attribute, student.Id),
                new XElement(_property, student.Name));

            students.Add(s);
        }

        XDocument document = new XDocument(students);

        try
        {
            document.Save(_fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"<--{ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

(тут есть опечатка в названии root :) )

А теперь создадим класс. который будет реализовывать IRepository

```
public class StudentsFileRepository : IRepository<Student>
{
    private readonly XmlFileService<Student> _fileService;

    //ctor
    public StudentsFileRepository(XmlFileService<Student> fileService)
    {
        _fileService = fileService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileService));
    }

    public IEnumerable<Student> Get()
    {
        return _fileService.ReadData();
    }

    public Student Get(int id)
    {
        return _fileService.ReadData().SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
    }

    public void Add(Student entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(entity));

        List<Student> students = new List<Student>(_fileService.ReadData());

        if (students.Any())
        {
            entity.Id = students.Max(e => e.Id) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            entity.Id = 1;
        }

        students.Add(entity);

        _fileService.WriteData(students);
    }

    public void Remove(Student entity)
    {
        if (entity == null || entity.Id == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(entity));

        List<Student> students = new List<Student>(_fileService.ReadData());

        Student student = students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == entity.Id);
        if (student == null) return;

        students.Remove(student);
        _fileService.WriteData(students);
    }
}
```

3) *Первые тесты работы или Консольный Интерфейс* Вообще говоря, тесты надо было писать сперва..., но мы все нарушим: во-первых, тесты будут только сейчас, во-вторых, это не юнит тесты, а просто тестовая проверка работы репозитория.

Создадим проект консольного приложения ConsoleUI, и в нем напишем след.

*Я забыл упоминуть ранее, что для библиотеки репозитория нужно добавить ссылку на проект Модели*, а в этом проекте нужно добавить ссылки на обе ранее созданные библиотеки
[image: добавление ссылок на библиотеки]

Теперь поработаем с моделью и репозиторием: добавить нового студента и отобразим это на экране

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsoleUI");
        Console.WriteLine();

        string file = @"D:\students.xml";
        XmlFileService<Student> fileService = new StudentFileService(file);
        StudentsFileRepository repo = new StudentsFileRepository(fileService);


        TestAddStudent("Вова", repo);

        List<Student> students = TestGetStudents(repo);

        ShowStudents(students);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ShowStudents(List<Student> students)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 30));

        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Студент{student.Id}: {student.Name}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 30));
    }

    private static List<Student> TestGetStudents(StudentsFileRepository repo)
    {
        return new List<Student>(repo.Get());
    }

    private static void TestAddStudent(string studentName, StudentsFileRepository repo)
    {
        repo.Add(new Student { Name = studentName });
    }
```

в итоге можно проверить, что файл записан
[image: содержимое xml файла]

4) *ViewModel* Вьюмодели, как правило, создают в том же проекте, где создаетcя WPF приложение, но в данном случае я намеренно создаю вьюмодель в отдельном проекте библиотеки, чтобы вы наглядно могли видеть, что VM не должна никоим образом зависеть от визуального интерфейса. Создайте библиотеку `StudVM`.

И начнем мы с интерфейса, в котором объявим несколько методов общения с пользователем программы, т.к. входе работы мы должны о чем-то сообщать пользователю или что-то спрашивать у него.

```
public interface IMainWindow
{
    bool AskUser(string message, string caption);
    void ShowError(string message, string caption);
    void ShowInfo(string message, string caption);
}
```

Теперь сам класс вьюмодели. Обратите внимание на конструктор, через него вьюмодель будет получать ссылки на реализации `IMainWindow` и `IRepository`. Сама вьюмодель реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly IMainWindow _mainWindow;
    private readonly IRepository<Student> _repository;

    public MainViewModel(IMainWindow mainWindow, IRepository<Student> repository)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainWindow));
        _repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
    }


    private ObservableCollection<Student> _Students;
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get { return _Students; }
        set
        {
            _Students = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Students)));
        }
    }


    private Student _CurrentStudent;
    public Student CurrentStudent
    {
        get { return _CurrentStudent; }
        set
        {
            _CurrentStudent = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentStudent)));
        }
    }


    public void LoadStudents()
    {
        var students = _repository.Get();

        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>(students);
    }

    public void NewStudent()
    {
        CurrentStudent = new Student { Name = "<Имя?>" };
    }

    public void AddNewStudent()
    {
        if (CurrentStudent == null
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentStudent.Name)
            || CurrentStudent.Name == "<Имя?>")
        {
            string message = "Не указано имя студента.";
            string caption = "Неверные данные студента";
            _mainWindow.ShowError(message, caption);

            return;
        }

        _repository.Add(CurrentStudent);
        CurrentStudent = null;

        LoadStudents();
    }

    public void RemoveStudent()
    {
        string message = "Вы согласны удалить студента?";
        string caption = "Согласие на удаление студента";

        if (CurrentStudent == null)
        {
            message = "Необходимо выбрать студента в списке.";
            caption = "Ошибка выбора студента для удаления";
            _mainWindow.ShowError(message, caption);

            return;
        }

        if (!_mainWindow.AskUser(message, caption))
        {
            CurrentStudent = null;
            return;
        }

        _repository.Remove(CurrentStudent);
        Students.Remove(CurrentStudent);

        CurrentStudent = null;
    }

}
```

Да, вы не забыли добавить в References ссылки на `StudBL`  `StudDAL`?

5) *Опять тесты* Вернемся к `ConsoleUI`, добавим ссылку на `StudVM` и

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsoleUI");
        Console.WriteLine();

        string file = @"D:\students.xml";
        XmlFileService<Student> fileService = new StudentFileService(file);
        StudentsFileRepository repo = new StudentsFileRepository(fileService);

        IMainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel(mainWindow, repo);

        vm.LoadStudents();
        ShowStudents(vm.Students.ToList());

        vm.NewStudent();
        vm.CurrentStudent.Name = "Сережа";

        vm.AddNewStudent();
        ShowStudents(vm.Students.ToList());


        //TestAddStudent("Вова", repo);

        //List<Student> students = TestGetStudents(repo);

        //ShowStudents(students);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Можете открыть файл и убедится в том, что добавился Сережа. `MainWindow` - это класс реализующий `IMainWindow` добавьте его в проект `ConsoleUI` и самостоятельно напишите сообщения пользователю через Console.WriteLine();

5) *WPF* Ну, наконец мы добрались до конечной цели.

Создайте проект WPF `WpfUI`, добавьте ссылки на наши библиотеки.
Интерфейс максимально простой, только ради демонстрации

```
<Canvas>
    <Button x:Name="buttonRemoveStudent" Content="Удалить"
            Canvas.Left="137" Canvas.Top="250" Width="75" Click="buttonRemoveStudent_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonNewStudent" Content="Новый"
            Canvas.Left="274" Canvas.Top="250" Width="75" Click="buttonNewStudent_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonAddStudent" Content="Добавить"
            Canvas.Left="368" Canvas.Top="250" Width="75" Click="buttonAddStudent_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="1.044,0.721"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxName" 
             Height="23" Canvas.Left="137"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text="{Binding CurrentStudent.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Canvas.Top="208" Width="248"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBoxStudents"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentStudent}"
             Height="136" Canvas.Left="137" Canvas.Top="20" Width="248">
    </ListBox>
</Canvas>
```

Обратите внимание на байдинг(биндинг) у листбокса: источником коллекции студентов является свойство `Students` у вьюмодели, а выделенным элементом - свойство `CurrentStudent`. У текстбокса привязка сделана к имени выбранного студента.

Последнее это кодбихайнд. Тут все просто, реализуем интерфейс `IMainWindow`, чтоб показывать пользователю программы сообщения. Обратите внимание на конструктор, где происходит загрузка необходимого и привязка DataContext окна к вьюмодели. Вызов методов для простоты сделан через события нажатия кнопок. Здесь будет критика со стороны опытных товарищей. Надо делать класс команд, который реализует `ICommand`. Я посчитал, что это выходит за рамки данного примера и расфокусирует внимание от главного.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IMainWindow
{
    private readonly string _file = @"D:\students.xml";
    private readonly MainViewModel _vM;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        XmlFileService<Student> fileService = new StudentFileService(_file);
        StudentsFileRepository repo = new StudentsFileRepository(fileService);

        _vM = new MainViewModel(this, repo);
        this.DataContext = _vM;

        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _vM.LoadStudents();
    }

    public bool AskUser(string message, string caption)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void ShowError(string message, string caption)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    public void ShowInfo(string message, string caption)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }

    private void buttonRemoveStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _vM.RemoveStudent();
    }

    private void buttonNewStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _vM.NewStudent();
    }

    private void buttonAddStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _vM.AddNewStudent();
    }
}
```

Запускаем и получаем это
[image: интерфес программы WPF]

Надеюсь, что это поможет понять общую архитектуру программы.
Скачать пример целиком можно [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/-lj-lXo53PZQ6f).

Comment: Может я скажу, что то не правильно, не судите строго. Насколько я понимаю суть Вашего скрипта сводится к одному - хранение данных в файле и обращение в файл по мере необходимости работы с данными. Что IMHO может сказаться на скорости работы программы. В принципе как идея - хорошая. Но только если бы можно работать с данными с любого M и не из файла, а из памяти, было бы замечательно. Пример в принципе полезный, сохранил, спасибо. Т.е. похоже для решения моей задачи без статичного класса данных не обойтись, как Вы думаете?

Comment: @KirillK. "Но только если бы можно работать с данными с любого M..." - что следует под этим понимать? Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что вы не понимаете, что же представляет собой понятие Модель. Статический класс - это всего лишь обертка над переменными и методами ( удобный способ получить таким образом "глобальные переменные и глобальные методы" в объектно-ориентированном языке), способ вернуться к привычному процедурному программированию.

Comment: @KirillK. в самом паттерне конечно нет прямых ограничений на использование статических классов для организации взаимодействия между V-VM-M, но для любого программиста, хорошо знающего этот паттер, будет очевидна сама абсурдность использования статических классов для его реализации.

Comment: Возможно я чего-то не понимаю, для того и спрашиваю что бы понять. Хорошо вот абстрактный пример во V пользователь задал путь к файлу, это все передалось VM. VM передал M. M обработал путь и создал еще VM1 и V1,. Затем передал путь в VM1 для V1 и пользователь может отредактировать путь в V1. Если пользователь редактирует, то все передается обратно (V1-VM1-M-VM-V). Так вот что бы избежать "тянучисти" пути из класса в класс + что бы не писать кучу событий и проверок, я нашел выход вынести путь в отдельный статический класс...

Comment: ...в нем создать событие на изменение в во всех нуждающихся классах подписаться на это событие. И пусть каждый класс к нему обращается. Да это своего рода глобальные переменные, но переменная то тоже затрагивает все глобально. Другого пути, в силу своих знаний, я пока не вижу. При этом судя по Вашим комментария я так понимаю этот вариант не comme il faut? Или есть другая альтернатива?

Comment: @KirillK. 1) Модель ничего не знает и не должна знать о существовании всяких VM и, тем более, V, потому никаких VM1 & V1 она создать не может и не должна, иначе это не модель, а черт знает что. 2) Вам следует аккуратно и внимательно, без изначального внутреннего сопротивления, изучить принципы и архитектуру примера, который я дал. 3) Модель - это класс Студент, он в VM представлен единичным экземпляром `CurrentStudent` и групповым, т.е. коллекцией студентов `Students`. 4) когда вы нажимаете кнопку Новый вы создаете новый экземпляр модели студент. 5) кнопка Добавить добавляет в коллекцию эту м.

Comment: @KirillK. почитайте внимательнее [статью](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php)

Comment: Понял... Что не чего не понял... Моя проблема видать кроется в не до понимание MVVM. Хорошо, но как M не чего не может знать о VM? Она же возвращает ему данные. Или имеется ввиду, что M не может вызывать методы VM? Т.е. сама M не генерирует данные и не передает VM? А только по запросу VM - метод M отрабатывает и возвращает какие-то данные или не возвращает не чего (пример VM говорит M сохранить данные и все)? Т.е не о какой двунаправленной связи не может идти речь в принципе. Точнее может, но только по запросу VM. Нет запроса - нет движения у M. Правильно я теперь понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

Паттерн MVVM не накладывает требования на взаимодействие VM и M. Дело в том, что обычно M пишется отдельно, другой командой, и вообще ничего не знает о MVVM.

Если вы видите, что ваша M дублирует вашу VM, возможно, вам просто не нужна модель в этом месте. Но если вы хотите сериализировать ваши настройки, то тогда да, модель будет нужна. В этом случае ничего страшного в копировании нет. Если вам не хочется копировать вручную, к вашим услугам кодогенерация или автомэпперы.

Comment: как я писал Bulson это нужно для обработки данных настройки, скажем пути, в BL (то есть в Model).

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам надо просто передать данные из `ViewModel` в `Model`?

Вот:

```
public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SomeModel SomeModel = new SomeModel();

    public SomeProperty SomeProperty
    {
        get { return ... }
        set 
        {
            // ... здесь какая-нибудь логика присвоения с вызовом события изменения свойства
            ...
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    ...

    public void SomeMethodToCall()
    {
        SomeModel.MethodThatGetSomeDataFromViewModel(SomeProperty);
    }
}
```

Просто через какую-нибудь любую функцию передать любое свойство/поле...

Comment: в прицепе Вы правильно поняли... 1. Интересует двусторонняя связь. 2. Я бы хотел избежать последовательной передачи, так как принимающий класс модели может быть не последним. Таким образом мы приходим ко 2-му мною описанному варианту.